# Is it possible to automate the moderation of a channel in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: outlook, active-directory, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

My organization recently implemented Microsoft Teams and is experiencing issues with users tagging @General unnecessarily, posting in the wrong channel, and posting inappropriate content (not necessarily NSFW but off-topic).

Slack has third-party tools that allow you to set rules for a channel and, if a rule is triggered, the message is automatically deleted. For example, if a user inadvertently tapped their yubikey and sent it to the entire organization, there is a bot that will recognize the key and immediately delete the message. It's effectively the same concept as the AutoMod functionality in Reddit.

I've been looking all over the place but can't seem to find any articles about this type of feature. Does Microsoft Teams allow for any functionality like this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Teams have functionalities such as sending notification from external app to Teams channel via incoming webhook. And also using proactive message notifications.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#get-the-user-id-or-teamchannel-id